# troubleshoot javascript chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, flask, web-frontend

I am attempting to pass csv data to render in the browser on a line chart. I can make this work with raw git csv data, reading the data directly into d3 with the raw git url.

For example this works the chart renders fine:

```
//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/FlaskAppData.csv",
//d3.csv({{data}},
```

But I am having issues passing the same data set from a backend flask app to the front end with this using jinja syntax `d3.csv({{data}},`. So most likely I am not doing something correctly on this step...

```
//Read the data
//d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/FlaskAppData.csv",
d3.csv({{data}},
```

The data is coming thru as shown in the screen shot below but there is also a `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` shown in fire fox dev tool console. Im confused why there would not be the same syntax error with the rawgit process...?

[image]

Would anyone have any ideas to try? This is the entire HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Load d3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
      .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //Read the data
    //d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/FlaskAppData.csv",
    d3.csv({{data}},
    

      // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
      function(d){
        return { date : d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")(d.Date), value : d.meter_reading }
      },

      // Now I can use this dataset:
      function(data) {

        // Add X axis --> it is a date format
        var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
          .range([ 0, width ]);
        xAxis = svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add Y axis
        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
          .range([ height, 0 ]);
        yAxis = svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // Add a clipPath: everything out of this area won't be drawn.
        var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("width", width )
            .attr("height", height )
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 0);

        // Add brushing
        var brush = d3.brushX()                   // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
            .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] )  // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
            .on("end", updateChart)               // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function

        // Create the line variable: where both the line and the brush take place
        var line = svg.append('g')
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

        // Add the line
        line.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("class", "line")  // I add the class line to be able to modify this line later on.
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
          .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
          .attr("d", d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
            )

        // Add the brushing
        line
          .append("g")
            .attr("class", "brush")
            .call(brush);

        // A function that set idleTimeOut to null
        var idleTimeout
        function idled() { idleTimeout = null; }

        // A function that update the chart for given boundaries
        function updateChart() {

          // What are the selected boundaries?
          extent = d3.event.selection

          // If no selection, back to initial coordinate. Otherwise, update X axis domain
          if(!extent){
            if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350); // This allows to wait a little bit
            x.domain([ 4,8])
          }else{
            x.domain([ x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1]) ])
            line.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null) // This remove the grey brush area as soon as the selection has been done
          }

          // Update axis and line position
          xAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisBottom(x))
          line
              .select('.line')
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("d", d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
              )
        }

        // If user double click, reinitialize the chart
        svg.on("dblclick",function(){
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
          xAxis.transition().call(d3.axisBottom(x))
          line
            .select('.line')
            .transition()
            .attr("d", d3.line()
              .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
              .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
          )
        });

    })


    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

For what its worth this is the flask app I am experimenting with. No errors in the python console...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import requests, time
from datetime import datetime
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def chart2():

    con = sqlite3.connect('./allData_new.db')
    df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from all_data", con)

    df2 = df[['Date','meter_reading']]
    df2 = df2.dropna()
    df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date']).dt.round('min').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
    data = df2.to_csv(index=False)
    df2.to_csv("FlaskAppData.csv",index=False)
    print(data)

    return render_template('line_chart3.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `)` after `d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/FlaskAppData.csv",`?

Comment: I think its at the very end of the </script>. Im using the code from here... https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_brushZoom.html

Comment: I dont understand why this works with the raw git but not passing the data from flask. In the link for the d3 tutorial, same way there is no `)`... Im definitely doing something wrong, trying to learn at the same time :( Thanks for any tips..